# Is the multiplicative constant in the Big O notation are ignored because of Linear Speed-Up theorem?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I just want to know if Big O notation was used as a consequences of the Linear speed up theorem or not. For me I guess the answer is yes.

For example, if we didn't have a linear speed-up theorem, then does it mean that we would have a different measure of time/space complexity? i.e. multiplicative constants does makes different. For example, $f(n) = 100 n$ isn't the same as $g(n)=10^{82}n$. Therefore, in this regard, Big O notation is not useful. So, probably we have another way to measure algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the big O notation was invented before the proof of the linear speedup theorem, and even before Turing machines.

Also, the big O notation often gives an information independant of the multiplicative constant: "if I multiply the input by $k$, then the total computing time will not be multiplied by more than …".

Finally, keep in mind that the linear speedup theorem gives a way to reduce the number of steps in the execution of a Turing Machine, but if you implement it on a real computer, it often also means that each step may be longer, so the real total time may not decrease.

The big O notation is a convenient way to compare asymptotic time complexity, but it is not always sufficient. For example, mergesort have an asymptotic complexity $\Theta(n\log n)$, but considering the multiplicative constant, it is often better to use insertion sort to sort small data, even if the asymptotic complexity of insertion sort is $\Theta(n^2)$ in average. Another example are [Fibonacci heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap#Worst_case).

Comment: Thank you Nathaniel, Yes I knew that Big O notation was designed before we know TM and it is my mistake that I didn't write this properly. 

I just want to ensure if people in the half of the last century were looking for some way to measure time/space complexity. So, they say Okay since multiplicative constants doesn't make difference (because of linear speed up theorem) and we know something called Big-O notation that ignore constant. Thus, Big-O notation is a good measure of time/space complexity. Was this the reason to bring up the Big-O notation or not